# Unable to create Sub web Programmatically in Feature Receiver

Tags: 2010, feature-receiver

I have write code in Feature Receiver to Create SubSite but while Feature is activating it returns the error

> **http://pc31:2000 contains illegal character ':'.**

This is My Code where I got Error. can anyone help me?

```
SPWeb newWeb = site.AllWebs.Add(web1.Url, "Custom Site", "Site description", 
    1033, "Publishing Site", true, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the relative url of the new site as the first parameter to the `AllWebs.Add()` function. Have a look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms412285.aspx

> A string that contains the new website URL relative to the root
>   website in the site collection. For example, to create a website at
>   http://intranet.contoso.com/sites/MySiteCollection/MyNewWebsite, specify
>   MyNewWebsite, or to create a website one level lower at
>   http://intranet.contoso.com/sites/MySiteCollection/Website/MyNewWebsite, specify
>   Website/MyNewWebsite.